# avm performance after spectre and meltdown

Tags: android, performance

Does anyone else notice that after windows updates about prevent spectre and meltdown issues, **`Android AVM`** run terribly slowly? these two things could be related?

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Having read some articles on the topic, both Google and Amazon as well as Intel have stated that the performance of the CPU's will be hit in exchange for security, but that hit will diminish over time, meaning that they work on applying both good security levels without having to pay for it with CPU frequency. 
In quotes: "any performance impacts are workload-dependent, and, for the average computer user, should not be significant and will be mitigated over time". However that doesn't seem to have happened yet, and maybe this could be an event for breakthrough changes in the CPU making history.